# Can't update cabal from 1.16 to 1.18

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I have cabal 1.16 installed and trying to update:

```
alex@cf:~# cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

Trying to update:

```
alex@cf:~# sudo cabal install --global cabal-install
cabal: There is no package named 'cabal-install'.
You may need to run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available
packages
```

At which point I run a `cabal update`, after which running `cabal install` returns the same as above. I followed by getting cabal from git, checking out 1.20.0.2 and run `sudo cabal install Cabal/ cabal-install/`

After a couple of minutes the prompt stops at that line:

```
[17 of 78] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription ( Distribution/PackageDescription.hs, dist/build/Distribution/PackageDescription.o )
```

with the following message:

```
[17 of 78] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription (Distribution/PackageDescription.hs, dist/build/Distribution/PackageDescription.o )
Failed to install Cabal-1.20.0.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Cabal-1.20.0.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 9
cabal-install-1.20.0.3 depends on Cabal-1.20.0.2 which failed to install.
```

Couldn't find anything about how to fix this and the error message is quite vague. Does anybody have any pointers? This is on a VPS running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-43-generic x86_64)

Thanks!

Comment: You should include the log file to see the details of the error, or run `cabal install ... -v3`. However, exit code 9 has to do with being out of memory - what are the specs of your machine?

Comment: It's a VPN running at DigitalOcean, 512 mb of memory. ``free -m`` shows 317 mb free before running ``cabal install...``. I guess I'll look into increasing the ram on this machine and see if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2407038 was right, the exit code 9 is caused by running out of memory. Upgrading the ram on the VPS fixed the issue.